# Variance of the autocovariance function at a particular lag

Tags: time-series, random-variable, autocorrelation, covariance, stochastic-processes

For a uniform random number(u) having mean $\mu$, the autocovariance at a lag $\tau$ is given by

$$C(\tau)=\frac{1}{N-\tau} \sum_{i=0}^{n-\tau} (u_i-\mu)(u_{i+\tau}-\mu)$$

For the uniformly distributed random number(u), 
$c(\tau)$ should normally distributed with mean of 0 and variance of $\frac{1}{144(n-\tau)}$ due to the central limit theorem. How can this be proved and how to arrive at the variance of $c(\tau)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$C(\tau)$ is normally distributed due to the Central limit theorem.

$E[C(\tau)] = \frac{1}{n-\tau}\sum_{i=1}^{n-\tau}E(u_i u_{i+\tau}) = 0.$

$Var[C(\tau)] = E[C(\tau)^2] - E[C(\tau)]^2 = E[C(\tau)^2]$

$E[C(\tau)^2] = E[\frac{1}{n-\tau}\sum_{i=1}^{n-\tau}u_i u_{i+\tau}\frac{1}{n-\tau}\sum_{j=1}^{n-\tau}u_j u_{j+\tau}] = \frac{1}{(n-\tau)^2}\sum_{i=1,j=1}^{n-\tau}E(u_i u_{i+\tau}u_j u_{j+\tau})$

$E(u_i u_{i+\tau}u_j u_{j+\tau}) = \begin{cases}
Var(u)^2 & \textbf{if} \hspace{.2cm} i = j \\
0  & \textbf{else} \\
\end{cases}.$

$u \sim Unif(0,1) \Rightarrow Var(u) = \frac{1}{12} \Rightarrow Var(u)^2 = \frac{1}{144}$

I.e. $E[C(\tau)^2] =  \frac{(n-\tau)}{(n-\tau)^2}\frac{1}{144} = \frac{1}{144(n-\tau)}$